# Recover a file filled with zeroes (nuls) after power loss

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, file-recovery

Can I recover the contents of a file which was filled by zeroes (nul bytes)? My notebook somehow lost power, and when I turned my machine back on, some of the files opened in a text editor were filled by zeroes. The size of both files remained intact but there's nothing but zeroes in the file:

[image: content of the file]

Comment: Is this for Windows 8 or for Windows XP?

Comment: It's for Windows 8 (8.1 actually) sorry for  tag xp rather than windows 8.1.

Comment: What text editor? Its kinda wierd that it would *save* the file as zeros. I'm also wondering if there might be a backup somewhere.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Mono Studio (or Xamarim Studio) Could be really great if the mono did the backup somewhere... I couldn't find anything related googling...

Comment: And It stopped working. I can't even compile a program without get an error which I've never seen before. I didn't reinstalled yet because I have some hope the get my files back.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions will only work if you have File History turned on.

You can attempt to restore files to a previous state using File History by following the instructions below:

> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap **Search** (or if you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click **Search**), enter **restore your files** in the search box, and then tap or click Restore your files with File History.
> 2. Enter the name of file you're looking for in the search box, or use the left and right arrows to browse through different versions of your folders and files.
> 3. Select what you want to restore to its original location, and then tap or click the **Restore** button.
>
> If you want to restore your files to a different location than the original, press and hold or right-click the **Restore** button, tap or click **Restore To**, and then choose a new location.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/how-use-file-history

---

If the above isn't an option then you can try rolling back to a previous Restore Point. This will roll your entire system back, so any legitimate file changes between the previous restore and now will be lost.

> To restore your PC to an earlier point in time:
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap **Search**.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click **Search**.)
> 2. Enter **Control Panel** in the search box, and tap or click **Control Panel**.
> 3. Enter **Recovery** in the Control Panel search box, and then tap or click **Recovery**.
> 4. Tap or click **Open System Restore**, and then follow the instructions.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc#

Comment: This is not turned on. I didn't even know about this feature. Why isn't this on by default?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it's probably because people would complain that Windows was creating multiple copies of files when they hadn't asked it to.

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried restore the system before created this topic but it didn't changed my files...

Answer (score 0):

Try a file undelete utility that looks in the "free space" of the drive to for lost files.

With any luck the zero-ed file didn't overwrite the data on the drive. Additionally, it would be best not to use that drive until you have recovered the file or had given up recovering the file because if the data is in the free space, just running the computer could overwrite the data (swap file writes, automatic defrag from Windows 8 maintenance task, browser cache, anything that writes to the disk could overwrite the data you are looking for).

I've used [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcinspector.de/Default.htm?language=1). I've heard people recommend [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds).

There are many free undelete utilities. If these programs can't find the data, then the data may have been overwritten and it probably would take professional tools to recover that data.

Comment: In case the zero-ed file didn't overwrite the data on the drive yet, how do I find it? how will these undelete tools show my zero-ed files? I tried PC inspector but it didn't show the file. Unfortunately, I'm using that drive because I have no other to search a solution on..

Comment: I'm considering a professional tool. Which one do you think will really work to recovery my zero-ed files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the titles of any truly professional tools. If it is that important, you will probably need to send the drive to a data recovery business like http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/. Some places have a deal that you only pay if they recover data. You should check with them to see if they can recover overwritten data or just do recover from damaged drives (like water damage). Sorry about the file, and good luck getting it back.